# Is a class containing two doubles a valid replacement for std::complex<double> parameters?

Tags: c++

Can a simple class with no virtual methods and with just two `double` data members be safely considered a "drop-in replacement" for `std::complex<double>` parameters?

In other words, assuming there is a function expecting an array of `std::complex<double>`, can the aforementioned class be used instead?

I tried with the following code, and it seems to work fine on the Visual C++ 2010 SP1 compiler. However, I'd like to know if this is something implementation-specific, or if it is officially supported by the standard.

---

Compilable code follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Point {
public:
    Point(double x, double y) 
        : _x(x), _y(y) { }

    // ... some non-virtual methods ...

private:
    double _x;
    double _y;
};

void f(const complex<double>* data, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        cout << "(" << data[i].real() << ", " 
             << data[i].imag() << ") ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<Point> points;
    points.push_back(Point(11.0, 22.0));
    points.push_back(Point(33.0, 44.0));
    points.push_back(Point(55.0, 66.0));

    f(reinterpret_cast<const complex<double>*>(points.data()),
      static_cast<int>(points.size()));
}
```

Output:

> ```
> C:\Temp\CppTests>cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo test.cpp
> test.cpp
>
> C:\Temp\CppTests>test.exe
> (11, 22) (33, 44) (55, 66)
> ```

Comment: Not unless it extends std::complex<double> or can be cast to it.

Comment: I'd say it's safe as long as `std::is_standard_layout<Point>::value == true` and `sizeof(Point) == sizeof(double[2])`, and of course the called methods are provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe.

The `Point` class is not POD (because of the constructor), but it is a "standard layout class".  The `complex<double>` type has a layout defined in the standard.

Comment: Problem #2 is a non-issue. The layout of `complex<double>` is defined in the standard (26.4p4): it must have the same size and representation as an array of two `double`s, where the first one represents the real part and the second the imaginary part.

Comment: I think, that if `std::complex<double>` is a POD type. Then ensuring the same for any class + providing the methods would be a sufficient to claim its compatibile. Therefore, I think, the only thing left is to make it trivially constructible. So the only thing that is missing (for c++11) is `Point() = default;`. The user-defined constructor, does not prohibit class from being POD. The lack of trivial default ctor does. Fast proof: http://ideone.com/yaCABc/

Comment: @luk32: I think this is not necessary, because POD is more than we need.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, but it's easy enough to ensure. And it would be a drop-in for any c functions. But of course you are right, even for non trivial ctor, `std::is_standard_layout<Point>::value` is true. Before I checked for POD only.

Comment: Sorry for double comment, but I wonder... Would you say, you can simplify it to the following statement: `(std::is_standard_layout<Point>::value == true) && (sizeof(Point) == sizeof(double[2]))`?

Comment: That looks good enough for me, except for the `== true` part.

Answer (score 1):

While what you have works and appears to be safe by all accounts, I would go for a cleaner solution. Create an operator that can cast a `Point` to a `std::complex<double>`.

```
class Point {
public:
    Point(double x, double y) 
        : _x(x), _y(y) { }

    operator std::complex<double> () const { return std::complex<double>(_x, _y); }

private:
    double _x;
    double _y;
};
```

You can refactor the function `f` to two:

```
void f(std::complex<double> const& data) {
    cout << "(" << data.real() << ", " 
       << data.imag() << ") ";
}

void f(const Point* points, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        f(points[i]); // Call the first function using the cast operator.
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

`main` can be made to look a little bit cleaner.

```
int main() {
    vector<Point> points;
    points.push_back(Point(11.0, 22.0));
    points.push_back(Point(33.0, 44.0));
    points.push_back(Point(55.0, 66.0));

    f(points.data(), static_cast<int>(points.size()));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that involve 2*double copy for each conversion? Not sure if this is feasible everywhere.

Comment: @luk32 That is true. Whether that cost is too much can only be determined by the use case.